# how to add id's to tr using loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add differnt id's on tr using jquery. I am writing this code but its give unique id to all. Please help for it.

```
var tableTr = $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr');
    var countTr= tableTr.size();
    for(i=0; i <= countTr-1; i++){
        alert(i);
            tableTr.attr('id', i);

        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You add id to `tableTr`. It is a collection of tr, not one of the trs.
Thanks to @C-linkNepal. `id` attribute can not start with number, you must add some letter before it.

```
tableTr.eq(i).attr('id', 'id' + i);
```

Comment: also id should not start with number do like .attr('id','someid-'+i)

Comment: it should be `tableTr.eq(i).attr('id', 'id' + i);` - `tableTr[i]` will return a dom element reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery each` to assign IDs to TR Element.It simply saves you the boilerplate code of incrementing the index and getting the value at that index.

```
    $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr').each(function(index){
       $(this).prop("id","id_"+index);
    });
```